# Confusion regarding composition of two spatial rotations of a sphere.

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, rotations, noneuclidean-geometry

I am currently studying Complex analysis from the book "Visual Complex Analysis" by Tristan Needham. In the chapter "Non-Euclidian Geometry" on page 282 the author says that the compostions of two Rotations is a Rotation and since a Rotation on a sphere can be decomposed into two reflections.
$$R_q^\phi\bullet R_q^\theta = (\mathcal{R_N\bullet R_M})\bullet (\mathcal{R_M \bullet R_L}) = \mathcal{R_N \bullet R_L} = \mathcal{R_r^\psi}$$

Then the author says that the angle $\psi$ can be found out by looking at the white spherical triangle. The area of the Triangle is $A$ and curvature of sphere is $k$ so the sum of the angles
$\theta/2 + \phi/2  + (\pi-\psi/2)= \pi + kA $  so  $\psi = \theta+\phi-2kA$. But this is not the formula that is written on the book. Where am i wrong?
[image]

Comment: As far as I can tell there is a small typo in that book. Otherwise it looks pretty good . Do you know if the formula $\psi=\theta+\phi-k{\cal A}$ is used somewhere?

Comment: No i don't see as far as i have read. But its weird that a famous book like this has a typo.